# Formatting using printf and format

Tags: java, formatting, scjp, ocpjp

In the following program

```
class ZiggyTest2 {

    public static void main(String[] args){     

        double x = 123.456;
        char c = 65;
        int i = 65;

        System.out.printf("%s",x);
        System.out.printf("%b",x);
        System.out.printf("%c",c);
        System.out.printf("%5.0f",x);
        System.out.printf("%d",i);
    }       
}
```

The output is

```
123.456trueA  12365
```

Can someone please explain how a double value (i.e. `123.456`) is converted to a boolean (ie. `true`)

The reason I ask is because I know java does not allow numbers to be used for boolean values. For example, the following is not allowed in Java

```
if (5) {
 //do something
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I think it's nice to point out that there is an important difference between the use of booleans in `if` statements versus in `printf`. That is, an `if` statement requires a primitive `boolean` (or a `Boolean` object, which will be unboxed). So any non-boolean value is not allowed. However, `printf` requires its arguments to be of type `Object`, i.e. any type. So, the compiler does not put any restrictions on the arguments to `printf`: even if they are primitive types like `boolean`, they can be boxed (to `Boolean`). This is why you can pass unexpected types to `printf` but not to `if`.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

**for "%b" :** If the argument arg is null, then the result is "false". If arg is a boolean or Boolean, then the result is the string returned by String.valueOf(). Otherwise, the result is "true".

[reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Comment: Yeah, so if you are C developer, be careful, because String.format("%b", 0) and String.format("%b", 1) will both return "true"

Answer (score 10):

The [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) seems to clearly state why.

> If the argument arg is null, then the result is "false". If arg is a boolean or Boolean, then the result is the string returned by
>   String.valueOf(). Otherwise, the result is "true".

Answer (score 0):

Because the value is of type `double` and this is how the `%b` converter works with values of this type.