# StringFormat for Java Boolean Operator

Tags: java

I know its very simple question. but I would like to know the stringformat for boolean operator. 
For example, below shows the string formats for integer, string and float. what could be for boolean operator true/false?

```
System.out.printf("The value of the float " +
                  "variable is %f, while " +
                  "the value of the " + 
                  "integer variable is %d, " +
                  "and the string is %s", 
                  floatVar, intVar, stringVar);
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Formatting using printf and format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629995/formatting-using-printf-and-format)

Answer (score 123, accepted):

'b' or 'B'     general     If the argument arg is null, then the result is "false". If arg is a boolean or Boolean, then the result is the string returned by String.valueOf(arg). Otherwise, the result is "true". 
java docs : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

[image]

Answer (score 48):

```
System.out.printf("boolean variable is %b",boolVar);
```

Answer (score 11):

One more way is -

```
    String output = String.format("boolean variable is %b",true);
    System.out.print(output);
```

Answer (score 9):

The placeholder for boolean is `%b`

Answer (score 4):

[System.out](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) is a [PrintStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) and the documentation for [PrintStream.printf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.util.Locale-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) links to the [format stream syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) which has a table of all of the conversions. The first entry in that table:

> `'b'`, `'B'` - If the argument *arg* is `null`, then the result is `"false"`. If *arg* is a `boolean` or `Boolean`, then the result is the string returned by `String.valueOf(arg)`. Otherwise, the result is `"true"`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
    float floatVar=1.0f;
    int intVar=1;
    String stringVar="hi";
    boolean boolVar=false;
    System.out.printf("The value of the float " +
                    "variable is %f, while " +
                    "the value of the " +
                    "boolean variable is %b, " +
                    "and the string is %s",
            floatVar, boolVar, stringVar);
```

`%b` is you are looking at