# Why is the output of Java String.format null Boolean false and how to String.format as null instead?

Tags: java, string-formatting

I'm sure that has been asked before, but I couldn't find the answer.

```
Boolean nullValue = null;
Boolean falseValue = false;
System.out.println( String.format( "%b %b", nullValue, falseValue ) );
```

How is the output of this "false false"?  That's exactly what I get out on my machine.  Java 8.  Mac.  Java noob.

EDIT

So this is the intended behavior.  It doesn't look like Boolean toString produces my desired behavior of outputting null, false, true either.  Is everyone who wants this supposed to write a method on their own?  Is there function that produces that output?

Comment: As a tip `System.out.println( String.format( "%b %b", nullValue, falseValue ) );` can be reduced as `System.out.printf("%b %b%n", nullValue, falseValue ) ;`, `%n` new line

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate, the question Jakg linked to is useful, but simply asks what the string format parameter for boolean is, not specifically how to handle getting null output accordingly.

Comment: `If the argument arg is null, then the result is "false"` is the beginning of the answer, does it seem related to yours now ?

Comment: Related yes, but it doesn't specifically address the best way of getting null, false, or true out of some toString function I'm not seeing as available.  Writing my own at this point, but wondering if I'm missing something.

Comment: You want to write null ? `Boolean a = null;   System.out.println(a);`

Comment: This is going into a logger that receives a format string and parameters.  I distilled it down specifically to System.println( String.format( ) ) as an SSCE to represent the problem I need to solve.

Comment: If you want null, true, false, then just use %s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look in the method `java.util.Formatter.FormatSpecifier.printBoolean(Object)` it only prints "true" if the variable is true - otherwise false is printed.

Looking further this has been covered in a previous [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24819098/3107019). This behavior is specified in the documentation.